# Saving java variables

Tags: java, loops, variables

I am working on an assignment and am unable to do a function because of this issue.

At the very beginning of the program I created a variable

```
int initial = Keyboard.nextInt() (obviously user input)
```

The program then goes into a loop in which the value of 'initial' is altered many times. However at the end of the program, when we exit the loop, I need to use the new 'initial' value and also the exact value that the user initially entered.

I am having difficulty getting the program to find the initial value because after exiting the loop any time I try to call on the 'initial' variable I only get the altered number not the first one the user entered. Help as to how I can solve this issue would be appreciated, thanks.

```
public class Question3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


                 //declare scanner 
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);


                //initial amount
                System.out.println("Enter the initial amount: ");
                int initial = keyboard.nextInt();

                int numItems = 0;
                double assets = 0;
                int originalPrice=initial; 
                double spending = originalPrice-assets;


                if(initial<=10)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please save money and come back later!!");
                    numItems=1;
                    spending=0.0;
                }
                else 
                    while (initial > 10 )
                {   
                    System.out.println("Do you want to make purchases (Y/N)? ");
                    char c = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                if (c == 'Y')
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please enter the price of the item = ");
                    }

                else 
                {
                        System.out.println("Lack of desire of Mr.Toto");
                        break;
                }

                int price = keyboard.nextInt();

                if (initial-price>=10)
                    {
                        System.out.println("A purchase is accepted");
                        initial-=price;
                        assets=initial-price;
                        numItems++;
                    }

                else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Insufficient assets!!");
                        System.out.println("Please enter the price of the item = ");
                    }
                if(numItems==10)
                {
                    System.out.println("Maximal number of purchases reached");
                    break;
                }


                }

                //displaying the summary of mr totos purchases 
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Here is a summary of Mr.Toto's purchases.");
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Number of items     Assets      Spending");
                System.out.println("    "+numItems+"                "+assets+"   " +"       "+spending);
                }
    }
```

Comment: just use separate variables for the new input and the old input

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow! you should look over the guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you should provide code examples etc.

For your question, all you would do is get int price = nextInt() like you said create another variable originalPrice = price. and call price for the new price and originalPrice for old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple errors.

- You are only dealing with `int` values so removed `doubles`.
- The `initialBalance` should be immutable, thus it is set `final`.
- The `spending` variable should have been initialized to `0`.

```java
package com.stackoverflow.q42588622;

import java.util.Scanner;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class Answer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // get in the habit of cleaning up resources
        try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            // initial amount
            System.out.println("Enter the initial amount: ");

            final int initialBalance = keyboard.nextInt();

            int numItems = 0;

            // Same concept as balance
            // Only dealing with ints 
            // double assets = 0.0;

            int balance = initialBalance;

            // Spending is initially 0.
            // Only dealing with ints
            // double spending = originalPrice - assets;

            int spending = 0;

            if (initialBalance <= 10) {
                System.out.println("Please save money and come back later!!");
                numItems = 1;
                spending = 0;
            } else {

                while (balance > 10) {

                    System.out.println("Do you want to make purchases (Y/N)? ");

                    char c = keyboard.next()
                        .charAt(0);

                    if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y') {
                        System.out.println("Please enter the price of the item = ");
                    }

                    else {
                        System.out.println("Lack of desire of Mr.Toto");
                        break;
                    }

                    int price = keyboard.nextInt();

                    if (balance - price >= 10) {
                        System.out.println("A purchase is accepted");
                        balance -= price;
                        spending += price;
                        // Removing as initialBalance is immutable
                        // assets = initial - price;
                        numItems++;
                    }

                    else {
                        System.out.println("Insufficient assets!!");
                        System.out.println("Please enter the price of the item = ");
                    }
                    if (numItems == 10) {
                        System.out.println("Maximal number of purchases reached");
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
            // displaying the summary of mr totos purchases
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Here is a summary of Mr.Toto's purchases.");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Number of items     Assets      Spending");
            System.out.println("    " + numItems + "                " + balance + "   " + "       " + spending);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using an ArrayList. For example:

```
//Inside loop
ArrayList<Integer> stuff = new ArrayList<>();
price = Keyboard.nextInt();
stuff.add(price);

//Outside loop; gets first input
stuff.get(0);
```